# JAXB: Unmarshalling similar XMLs with varying namespaces

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb

I am getting 3 different xml input from 3 different clients:

Input 1 from Client 1: (namespace-prefix: `ns2`, namespace-url: `url1`)

```
<ns2:myroot xmlns:ns2="url1">
   <ns2:mydata>
      <ns2:myrate>
         GBP 800.55
      </ns2:myrate>
   </ns2:mydata>
</ns2:myroot>
```

Input 2 from Client 2: (namespace-prefix: `ns5`, namespace-url: `url2`)

```
<ns5:myroot xmlns:ns5="url2">
   <ns5:mydata>
      <ns5:myrate>
         THB 1000.70
      </ns5:myrate>
   </ns5:mydata>
</ns5:myroot>
```

Input 3 from Client 3: (namespace-prefix: `<empty>`, namespace-url: `url3`)

```
<myroot xmlns="url3">
   <mydata>
      <myrate>
         USD 955.25
      </myrate>
   </mydata>
</myroot>
```

All 3 of them have same element names but different namespaces. So I wrote down 1 package of class files named `MyRoot.java` and `MyData.java`:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="myroot")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyRoot
{   @XmlElement(name="mydata")
    protected MyData mydata;
    public MyData getMyData()
    {   return mydata;
    }
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyData
{   @XmlElement(name="myrate")
    protected String myRate;
    public String getMyRate()
    {   return myRate;
    }
}
```

Here is how I tested it:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[]ar){
        for(String inputFileName:new String[]{"input3.xml","input2.xml","input1.xml"}){
            try{
                MyRoot myRoot = (MyRoot) JAXBContext.newInstance(MyRoot.class).createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data/xml/jaxb/varns/"+inputFileName));
                System.out.println(myRoot.getMyData());
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Problem is:

1. If I add `namespace="url3"` to `@XmlRootElement` / `@XmlElement`, then I get: `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"url1", local:"myroot"). Expected elements are <{url3}myroot>` and `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"url2", local:"myroot"). Expected elements are <{url3}myroot>`
2. If I add `namespace="url2"` to `@XmlRootElement` / `@XmlElement`, then I get: `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"url1", local:"myroot"). Expected elements are <{url2}myroot>` and `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"url3", local:"myroot"). Expected elements are <{url2}myroot>`
3. If I add `namespace="url1"` to `@XmlRootElement` / `@XmlElement`, then I get: `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"url2", local:"myroot"). Expected elements are <{url1}myroot>` and `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"url3", local:"myroot"). Expected elements are <{url1}myroot>`

My Question is:

Is there any way I can make this code suitable for varying namespaces?

**-------------------------------------------------**

Edit after Blaise Doughan's answer:

-------------------------------------------------

Since I needed the code to work for different namespaces for each input, I made following change s in the code:

1. Made the variable `NAMESPACE` in `NamespaceFilter` non-static.
2. Changed the `Demo.java` code to `MyRootUtils.java` that has mehtod named `getMyRoot`
3. On using `JaxbContext.newInstance("url1")` I found that there is no such `newInstance()` which takes `namespace-url` as an argument. So I changed it to: `newInstance(Myroot.class)`.
4. Changed the `Test.java` to suit the new classes.

MyRootUtils.java

```
package data.xml.jaxb.varns1;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.*;
public class MyRootUtils {
    public static MyRoot getMyRoot(String prefix,String url,InputStream xml) throws Exception {
        // Create the JAXBContext
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyRoot.class);//(MyRoot.class);
        // Create the XMLFilter
        XMLFilter filter = new NamespaceFilter(prefix,url);
        // Set the parent XMLReader on the XMLFilter
        filter.setParent(SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader());
        // Set UnmarshallerHandler as ContentHandler on XMLFilter
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = unmarshaller.getUnmarshallerHandler();
        filter.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);
        // Parse the XML
        filter.parse(new InputSource(xml));
        return (MyRoot) unmarshallerHandler.getResult();
    }
}
```

NamespaceFilter.java

```
package data.xml.jaxb.varns1;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl;
public class NamespaceFilter extends XMLFilterImpl {
    private final String NAMESPACE,PREFIX;
    public NamespaceFilter(String prefix,String url) {
        PREFIX=prefix;
        NAMESPACE=url;
    }
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("::Into endElement(uri,localName,qName):: [uri: "+uri+"],[localName: "+localName+"],[qName: "+qName+"];");
        super.endElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName);
    }
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,Attributes atts)
            throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("::Into startElement(uri,localName,qName,atts):: [uri: "+uri+"],[localName: "+localName+"],[qName: "+qName+"];");
        super.startElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName, atts);
    }
    @Override
    public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri)
            throws SAXException {
        System.out.println(prefix+"="+uri);
        super.startPrefixMapping(PREFIX, NAMESPACE);
    }
    @Override
    public void endPrefixMapping(String prefix) throws SAXException {
        super.endPrefixMapping(PREFIX);
    }        
}
```

Test.java

```
package data.xml.jaxb.varns1;
import java.io.InputStream;    
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[]ar){
        String[] files={"input3.xml","input2.xml","input1.xml"};
        String[] urls ={"url3","url2","url1"};
        String[] prfs ={"","ns5","ns2"};
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i){
            try{
                String prefix=prfs[i];
                String url = urls[i];
                InputStream xml = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data/xml/jaxb/varns1/"+files[i]);
                MyRoot myRoot = MyRootUtils.getMyRoot(prefix,url, xml);
                System.out.println(myRoot.getMyData().getMyRate());
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getCause());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I still got this output:

```
::Into startElement(uri,localName,qName,atts):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: myroot];
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"url3", local:"myroot"). Expected elements are <{}myroot>
::Into startElement(uri,localName,qName,atts):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: ns5:myroot];
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"url2", local:"ns5:myroot"). Expected elements are <{}myroot>
::Into startElement(uri,localName,qName,atts):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: ns2:myroot];
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"url1", local:"ns2:myroot"). Expected elements are <{}myroot>
```

Which meant something was missing.

Here is the full stacktrace of one of the exceptions(namespace without prefix):

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"url3", local:"myroot"). Expected elements are <{}myroot>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:648)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:236)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:231)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1051)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:484)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:465)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:60)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:135)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:527)
    at data.xml.jaxb.varns1.NamespaceFilter.startElement(NamespaceFilter.java:20)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:767)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1315)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3104)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:921)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
    at data.xml.jaxb.varns1.MyRootUtils.getMyRoot(MyRootUtils.java:31)
    at data.xml.jaxb.varns1.Test.main(Test.java:15)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"url3", local:"myroot"). Expected elements are <{}myroot>
    ... 27 more
```

Here is another stacktrace (namespace with prefix):

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"url2", local:"ns5:myroot"). Expected elements are <{}myroot>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:648)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:236)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:231)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1051)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:484)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:465)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:60)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:135)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:527)
    at data.xml.jaxb.varns1.NamespaceFilter.startElement(NamespaceFilter.java:20)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:767)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1315)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3104)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:921)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
    at data.xml.jaxb.varns1.MyRootUtils.getMyRoot(MyRootUtils.java:31)
    at data.xml.jaxb.varns1.Test.main(Test.java:15)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"url2", local:"ns5:myroot"). Expected elements are <{}myroot>
... 27 more
```

Adding `namespace="url1"` is of no use either, as I still got same stack of exceptions.

The output: (without `namespace="url1"`)

```
::Into startElement(uri,localName,qName,atts):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: ns5:myroot];
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"url2", local:"ns5:myroot"). Expected elements are <{}myroot>
```

The output: (with `namespace="url1"`)

```
::Into startElement(uri,localName,qName,atts):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: ns2:myroot];
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"url1", local:"ns2:myroot"). Expected elements are <{url1}myroot>
```

Shows that namespace resolution is not yet complete.

Finally, I made 2 more changes:

1. I used the `.replace("old-string","new-string")` method of `String` class in `NamespaceFilter.java` to reduce `qName` (The fully qualified element-name), like this:

   `super.endElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName);`

   changed to:

   `super.endElement("", localName, qName.replace(PREFIX+":", ""));`
2. `super.startElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName, atts);`

   changed to:

   `super.startElement("", localName, qName.replace(PREFIX+":", ""), atts);`

Code for `NamespaceFilter.java`:

```
package data.xml.jaxb.varns1;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl;
public class NamespaceFilter extends XMLFilterImpl {
    private final String NAMESPACE,PREFIX;
    public NamespaceFilter(String prefix,String url) {
        PREFIX=prefix;
        NAMESPACE=url;
    }
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("::Into endElement(uri,localName,qName):: [uri: "+uri+"],[localName: "+localName+"],[qName: "+qName+"];");
        super.endElement("", localName, qName.replace(PREFIX+":", ""));
    }
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,Attributes atts)
            throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("::Into startElement(uri,localName,qName,atts):: [uri: "+uri+"],[localName: "+localName+"],[qName: "+qName+"];");
        super.startElement("", localName, qName.replace(PREFIX+":", ""), atts);
    }
    @Override
    public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri)
            throws SAXException {
        System.out.println(prefix+"="+uri);
        super.startPrefixMapping(PREFIX, NAMESPACE);
    }
    @Override
    public void endPrefixMapping(String prefix) throws SAXException {
        super.endPrefixMapping(PREFIX);
    }
}
```

The output now is:

```
::Into startElement(uri,localName,qName,atts):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: myroot];
::Into startElement(uri,localName,qName,atts):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: mydata];
::Into startElement(uri,localName,qName,atts):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: myrate];
::Into endElement(uri,localName,qName):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: myrate];
::Into endElement(uri,localName,qName):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: mydata];
::Into endElement(uri,localName,qName):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: myroot];
USD 955.25
::Into startElement(uri,localName,qName,atts):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: ns5:myroot];
::Into startElement(uri,localName,qName,atts):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: ns5:mydata];
::Into startElement(uri,localName,qName,atts):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: ns5:myrate];
::Into endElement(uri,localName,qName):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: ns5:myrate];
::Into endElement(uri,localName,qName):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: ns5:mydata];
::Into endElement(uri,localName,qName):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: ns5:myroot];
THB 1000.70
::Into startElement(uri,localName,qName,atts):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: ns2:myroot];
::Into startElement(uri,localName,qName,atts):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: ns2:mydata];
::Into startElement(uri,localName,qName,atts):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: ns2:myrate];
::Into endElement(uri,localName,qName):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: ns2:myrate];
::Into endElement(uri,localName,qName):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: ns2:mydata];
::Into endElement(uri,localName,qName):: [uri: ],[localName: ],[qName: ns2:myroot];
GBP 800.55
```

However, this raises a few concerns:

1. Ignores the namespace completely.
2. Calls `String.replace()` each time there is a `startElement()` & `endElement()`

It makes me think if this approach for variable-namespace should be acceptable at all.
If there is anything that can be done to improve this code, then I request the community to mention it in the answers/comments and help do away with this probably flawed approach.

Answer (score 1):

## Handling of XML from Primary Namespace

For any XML that corresponds directly to the namespace that you have mapped to in the Java model you can marshal/unmarshal it normally

## Handling of XML from Secondary Namespaces

### Unmarshalling

You can apply a SAX `XMLFilter` when unmarshalling to that when you are processing an XML document that corresponds to the schema with namespace `url2` it appears as though it corresponds to the schema with namespace `url1`.

```
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl;

public class NamespaceFilter extends XMLFilterImpl {

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "url1";

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        super.endElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName);
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName, atts);
    }

}
```

**Demo Code**

Here is some sample code demonstrating how to apply the `XMLFilter`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create the JAXBContext
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("url1");

        // Create the XMLFilter
        XMLFilter filter = new NamespaceFilter();

        // Set the parent XMLReader on the XMLFilter
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        filter.setParent(xr);

        // Set UnmarshallerHandler as ContentHandler on XMLFilter
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = unmarshaller
                .getUnmarshallerHandler();
        filter.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);

        // Parse the XML
        InputSource xml = new InputSource("input.xml");
        filter.parse(xml);
        Object result = unmarshallerHandler.getResult();
    }

}
```